# DDMS multi-user debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, windows-10, ddms

I am trying to run 2 instances of Android studio 3.1.1 on 2 separate windows 10 accounts (each user with its instance) running at the same time (i applied termsrv.dll patch), so far everything works fine except debugging. Each user runs his emulator independently, the problem is that only one user can debug the other gets this message:

> Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700). Make sure you do not have another instance of DDMS or of the eclipse plugin running. If it's being used by something else, choose a new port number in the preferences.

I tried configuring each AStudio with its own android sdk installation but still the problem persists.
Another thing i tried was to change the DDMS debugger port, still no changes.

What else should i try ?

[image]